# Context used outside of provider error - nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm migrating to nextjs 13 from nextjs 12 and I have a few problems with the new app/ folder, I get this error when I try to launch the application with the login/ route:

```js
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: context used outside of provider.
```

**app/layout.tsx**:

```js
export default function RootLayout({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

    return (
        <html lang="en">
        <body>
        <Provider>
            {children}
        </Provider>
        </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

I have the 'use client' on top of the provider.tsx

**app/provider.tsx**

```js
const Provider = ({children}: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState<Auth | undefined>(undefined);
    const [user, setUser] = useState<User | undefined>(undefined);
    const [config, setConfig] = useState<IPCConfig | undefined>(undefined);
    const [error, setError] = useState<Error | unknown>(undefined);
    const toast = useToast();
    const [files, setFiles] = useState<IPCFile[]>([]);
    const [sharedFiles, setSharedFiles] = useState<IPCFile[]>([]);
    const [folders, setFolders] = useState<IPCFolder[]>([]);
    const [programs, setPrograms] = useState<IPCProgram[]>([]);
    const [sharedPrograms, setSharedPrograms] = useState<IPCProgram[]>([]);
    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState<IPCContact[]>([]);
    const [path, setPath] = useState('/');

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!auth && !error) {
            try {
                setAuth(new Auth());
            } catch (e) {
                setError(e);
            }
        }
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (error) {
            toast({
                title: 'Internal Server Error',
                status: 'error',
                isClosable: true,
            });
        }
    }, [error]);

    return (
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme} resetCSS cssVarsRoot="body">
            <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode}/>
            <AuthContext.Provider value={auth}>
                <UserContext.Provider value={{user: user as User, setUser}}>
                    <ConfigContext.Provider value={{config: config as IPCConfig, setConfig}}>
                        <DriveContext.Provider
                            value={{
                                files,
                                setFiles,
                                sharedFiles,
                                setSharedFiles,
                                folders,
                                setFolders,
                                sharedPrograms,
                                setSharedPrograms,
                                programs,
                                setPrograms,
                                contacts,
                                setContacts,
                                path,
                                setPath,
                            }}
                        >
                            {children}
                        </DriveContext.Provider>
                    </ConfigContext.Provider>
                </UserContext.Provider>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        </ChakraProvider>
    )
}
```

**src/contexts/auth.ts**

```js
import {createContext, useContext} from 'react';

import Auth from 'lib/auth';

type AuthContextType = Auth | undefined;

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(undefined);

const useAuthContext = (): Auth => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext);
    if (!context) throw new Error('context used outside of provider.');
    return context;
};
```

I'm trying to test the login page but I get the error that I showed up.

Comment: You forgot to wrap your application inside the `AuthContext.Provider` component. Check out the [section regarding context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) inside the official react docs to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your initial `auth` value.

```js
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<Auth | undefined>(undefined);
```

This is `undefined` and once you use your `useAuthContext` hook there is no 'real' value and it throws the error.

```js
if (!context) throw new Error("context used outside of provider.");
```

You can solve this by directly setting a `new Auth()` as the initial state.

```js
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<Auth>(new Auth());
```

The use of a `useEffect` in this case is not really needed since it is only used to set a initial value for the state.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I've been searching for hours :D.